# Trying to work with the mapping function and it keeps gives me this error?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-devtools

[TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUW8p.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUW8p.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUW8p.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/jObmG.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe posts is undefined at the first rendering because it comes from an async call.

```
export default function Post({ posts = []}) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Did what you suggested and it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: If this solved the problem you can consider to accept the answer so that other users with the same problem can see the solution.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the **posts** array is empty. We can help better if you show us the posts object

Comment: It's not an empty array, it's undefined. It's the only possibility in fact from this code